# Keep colours of cells when using autofill (Excel)

Tags: excel, colors, autofill

I have a formula in Excel that I would like to drag down to other cells using autofill. However, the cells below have unique colours and I do not want to remove them. Is there an easy way of autofilling the cells with my formula and keeping the colours?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By hand? As in using Excel and not programming it? Just click the *Auto Fill Options* (the "thingy" that appears when you stop dragging) and choose *Fill Without Formatting*. Or `Copy` the source cell and then just `Paste Special` and choose *Formulas*.

Comment: By hand, yes. That works well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way I have found is to drag using the right mouse button and when you release the button the options menu will popup automatically, just select "Fill Without Formatting".